# Put circle over google map

Tags: android

I have map ( GeoActivity ) in my app. I need to mark some region with circle, circle need to move with finger touch . How to achieve that ?
I need something similar like http://www.apartmentfinder.com/Georgia/Atlanta-Apartments
when you go on personalize your search .

Any idea, advice ?

Comment: This library may help - https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you looked at following post [Creating Custom Overlay on the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428730/creating-custom-overlay-on-the-map)