# how to display google like current location icon in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

friends,

i want to add google like circular current location icon in my application

as given in example any one guide me how to achieve this?

is this simple image or what?

any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an ItemizedOverlay, if you are speaking about google maps on Android.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428730/creating-custom-overlay-on-the-map) stackoverflow question and see the code and links in the posts.